# Поиск элемента через Linq

Tags: c#, unity3d, linq

Есть некоторый класс, который висит на объектах `ob1` и каждому присвоен индивидуальный `index`.

```
public class CustomClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public int index;
}
```

В основном классе находится динамический массив таких объектов вида:

```
List<List<GameObject>> allObjects = new List<List<GameObject>>();
allObjects.Add(new List<GameObject> { ob1, ob2});
allObjects.Add(new List<GameObject> { ob1, ob2});
allObjects.Add(new List<GameObject> { ob1, ob2});
```

Элементы в `allObjects` могут идти не по порядку. Подскажите, как найти позицию динамического массива `List<GameObject>` в `allObjects`, в котором `ob1` содержит нужный индекс в `CustomClass`? Хочется реализовать это через **Linq**. Пробовал наподобие такой конструкции:

```
allObjects.Select(x => x[0].GetComponent<CustomClass>().index == i)
```

но не уверен, что это правильно и не знаю как далее получить позицию элемента в `allObjects`, для которого условие выполнено. Подскажите как это реализовать через **Linq**.

Comment: @aepot оформите как ответ, приму

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Select` преобразует последовательность через делегать, а чтобы искать первый элемент по условию, есть `First` или `FirstOrDefault`.

```
var list = allObjects.First(x => x[0].GetComponent<CustomClass>().index == i);
```

Можно получить и индекс, правда непонятно, зачем

```
int index = allObjects.IndexOf(list);
```